# Deriving Chi-Square formula for contingency table 2x2

Tags: shortcut, derivative, chi-squared, alternate

Given a 2x2 contingency table, with a, b, c, and d as the observed values and n as the total, I have to show from the fact that

`Chi-Square = sum(((O-E)^2)/E)`

Where O is the observed value, and E is the expected value of the observed, that:

`Chi-Square= (n(ad-bc)^2)/(a+b)(a+c)(b+d)(c+d)`

I just can't seem to get there. Any links or tips about how this formula is derived?

Comment: This is something I was looking for a long time. My major was in Biology. It doesn't affect my work, but I am curious about how to get to the final equation. This question was asked before here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1704169/proof-for-chi-squared-contingency-tables with more details.